# Play-Slick : Library dependency with database

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have several scala-play apps in my service that use play-slick for FRM.

I'd like to write a library that abstracts away some common code that is used across these services. This library needs to create DB tables, so will come with their own evolution scripts.

Can someone point me to a sample code/pattern of how this can be done without the libraries evolution code conflicting with the apps' own evolution scripts